# mColorPicker error 'Invalid Property value' in IE7

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have recently downloaded mColorPicker.js from [here](http://code.google.com/p/mcolorpicker/downloads/detail?name=mColorPickerv1r30.zip&can=2&q=)

However, I am running into some issue with this -
When user enters an invalid color value like '#454545xxxx' in the color box, I get a js error - Invalid Property value in IE7 (working fine in Firefox)

error is coming in
jquery-1.4.2.min.js,

line 116 - `if(e)f[b]=d`

```
when d = "#454545xxxx"
```

Also, ColorPicker image is hidden for this textbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you linked to the right plugin? The mColorPicker plugin doesn't have a "jQuery.colorbox.js" file in it. Perhaps you are confusing the two?

Comment: Sorry, typo :-( it was actually jquery-1.4.2.min.js updated my quest.

Comment: Are you serving the mColorPicker.js file yourself? In other words, can you make modifications to it?

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded mColorPicker.js and included in my solution

Comment: Yes, i had the same error, when i was setting the "background-color" property to "#fff !important" using .css() method in jquery
.css("background-color", "#fff !important"); it works fine in IE9 though. i wonder if the latest version of jquery solved this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that the plugin is trying to set the value of the background colour to exactly what the user typed, without doing any validation checking to make sure it is a valid colour. The plugin calls the jQuery `.css()` method to do this, which is why the error is occurring inside jquery-1.4.2.min.js.

If you are able to modify the plugin code, you can then add checks to make sure the value entered is a valid colour before proceeding.

You might also suggest adding this feature to the plugin author, or, if you get it working successfully, submitting your updated code to them so they can benefit from your work.

I had a quick look, but I don't have the time to properly make the necessary changes to the plugin to ensure it correctly validates the colour is valid in all the right places. Good luck!